# Unit testing file operations - where to maintain mock directory structure?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm still new to Unit testing, and specifically [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/) as the testing framework.

Suppose I'm building a unit test for a resource loader class. The class looks for resources to load in two directories (a global and a user-specific one).

To test the class, I would like to set up a mock testing directory containing some resource files. I would like to put the mock directory somewhere within the test suite (the suite is part of a web application that will get distributed.)

Is there a convention for where to put this testing directory in the context of a PHPUnit test suite composed using the file system as outlined [here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.filesystem)?

Is there a way (e.g. a constant defined by PHPUnit when it runs the test) to access such a mock directory from within a unit test without having to specify its exact location, i.e. a path relative to the current test suite? Or do I just use `dirname(__FILE__)` and compose an absolute path from that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the resource loader looks for files in directories and you want to test the loader's correct interaction with these directories, you should [mock the filesystem](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-the-filesystem). If you test with a real directory, you are risking outside change to these directories that may affect the test outcome. Using the vfs is also *much* faster.

Comment: I must be missing something here. The link you posted shows how to create an empty virtual filesystem, with examples that use `mkdir` and `rmdir`, but it sounds like the OP was asking how to ship mock files with the test, which will be available for the test code to read. (That's what I'm trying to do. Hopefully I didn't misunderstand the OP's question.)